# Ensuring static property is defined in derived classes

Tags: c#, static

I have a requirement where each class must have a static read-only property to avoid magic strings. Initially, I thought of creating a base class enforcing that each derived class implements the static read-only property. Since an interface, or an abstract property can't be used for this. Is there a way to achieve this in C#?
Currently, I have the following workaround in my mind, but I can easily see it resulting in confusion in the future i.e.,

#### Base Class

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual string StaticProperty { get; }
}
```

#### Derived Class

```
public abstract class Derived : Base
{
    public new static string StaticProperty => "Some Value";
}
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Can you give us a concrete example on how your code is supposed to be used?

Comment: @RuiJarimba One concrete example could be any derived class must have the table name as a static string to avoid magic strings.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why does the derived type need to define a **static** property **specifically**?

Comment: @ZerosAndOnes not sure if I understood your problem, but check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understood your problem, but I think the solution is pretty simple. Do you really need a static property?? If not, just add a private constructor with a parameter to initialize the property:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public string StaticProperty { get; }

    protected Base(string staticProperty)
    {
        StaticProperty = staticProperty ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(staticProperty));
    }
}
```

Then, in the derived class, invoke the base constructor (otherwise you'll get a compilation error):

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(string staticProperty) : base(staticProperty)
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see, without invoking the base constructor you'll get a compilation error:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this led me in the right direction since static property can also be accessed in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is there is no constraint forcing you to implement it, so defining it in the base class seems redundant anyway.

Unfortunately the alternatives are just as questionable and have the same problem, namely that you have to make a new branch for each derived class.

```
public abstract class Derived : Base
{

}
public static class Helper<T> where T : Base
{
   public static string SomeProperty => GetMyProperty();

   public static string GetMyProperty()
   {
      if (typeof(T) == typeof(Derived))
      {
         return "asd";
      }

      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var test = Helper<Derived>.SomeProperty;

// or

var test = Helper<Derived>.GetMyProperty();
```

Another option might be to use attributes, however it depends how you want to go about getting these values out, you will still need a helper or a static property to retrieve them anyway

```
[MyAttribute("SomeName","SomethingElse")]
public abstract class Derived : Base
```

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> One concrete example could be any derived class must have the table name as a static string to avoid magic strings.

So you want to make sure that such a property exists presumably because you want to access it using reflection. Write a unit test that reflects over all such types and uses reflection to make sure that they contain a static property.

The C# type system cannot help you here. Write a unit test to assert this structure.